# Where can I find a python example for the Parallax MS5607 Altimeter?

Tags: i2c, pi-3

I'm looking for some python examples that show how to use the Parallax MS5607 Altimeter/Barometer/Thermometer with a Raspberry Pi 3. I'm new to I2C and thought this might be a good way to jump in with both feet. I have a problem that needs solving (log some environmental data points) and the tools (pi3, MS5607, python) so it seemed like a good start except I may have jumped in the deep end; I'm a little short on resources, like code examples.

Any recommendations for resources to connect this altimeter?

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/rsolomon/py-MS5607

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you need to check:

1. Can you detect your sensor.
   use `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`
2. If you can then read datasheet for commands.
   If not make sure hardware and software are working. For software you will need to install smbus library.
   If software is installed then check your hardware make sure your I2C voltage level are correct.
   Or you can get a [pi shield](https://www.controleverything.com/content/I2C-Master?sku=TOUTPI2) like this which will do all hardware conversion for you.
3. now lets assume all your software and hardware is working and you can detect the sensor.
   Although you can get a new version of MS5607, MS5803-02BA_I2CS, you can plug this directly into your pi. Lot of time your project doesn't work because you didn't connect the hardware properly but this will eliminate that.
4. now lets say everything working fine, lets move to the code. You can find 100s I2C python/java/arduino code, in your case you will need this code [python,java i2c code for altimeter raspberry pi3](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/MS5803-02BA)